# Dnn Ver 9.4.0 Install package not running

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

I have downloaded the dnn version -9.4.0 install package from url -https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/releases/tag/v9.4.0  and configured that with IIS server but it's not running.I am getting compile time errors.

According to it's release document I have upgraded .net framework (4.7.2) in my system as well.

Same Install package for ver-9.2.2 I have downloaded then configured that in IIS and it's running proper.

Can you please confirm me about the issue in 9.4.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a few more details?

As an aside, you might want to check out nvQuickSite as an aid in installing DNN.

Answer (score 0):

There were some issues with 9.4.0, but mostly about upgrades. Please try to download and install 9.4.1 which was released recently and addresses these issues.